# How to delete particular row from angular material table which doesnt have filters?

Tags: angular, mat-table

My samplepage.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-batchticketvalidation',
  templateUrl: './batchticketvalidation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./batchticketvalidation.component.css']
})
export class BatchticketvalidationComponent {

  constructor() { }

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'ticketnumb', 'actionsColumn'];
  dataSource: PeriodicElement[] = ELEMENT_DATA;
  private myDataArray: any;

  deleteTicket(rowid: number) {
    if (rowid > -1) {
      this.myDataArray.splice(rowid, 1);
    }
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  id: number;
  ticketnumb: string;
  actionsColumn: any;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
];
```

My samplepage.component.html

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myDataArray" >
   <!-- <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" >
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element[column]}} </td>
      </ng-container> -->

   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketnumb">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ticket Number </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ticketnumb}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="actionsColumn">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;  let j = index;"> 
         <button mat-raised-button  color="warn" focusable="false" (click)="deleteTicket(j)">
         <i class="fa fa-times mat-icon"></i> Remove
         </button>
      </td>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I am new to angular. I need help in removing particular row from the table and once the row is removed the table should get refresh or it should show the existing data. I have only static rows. This is just a plain mockup html that i want to show to the client.

Each row has delete button and on click of delete button I am calling deleteTicket(rowid).

When deleteTicket method is triggered, the row is **not removed** from Ui, but when i console this.myDataArray, the data is removed from object.

I tried all possibilities.

Comment: You could try -
this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();

Comment: @rakesh supply your new `this.myDataArray` as new datasource object. you can use like `this.myDataArray= new MatTableDataSource(this.myDataArray);` after splicing the array

Answer (score 53):

after `splice()` by index of item, you should update the **datasource**.

```
const index = this.dataSource.data.indexOf(item.id);
this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription(); // <-- Refresh the datasource
```

Comment: you should use `this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1)` otherwise the `splice` method will remove every item with a higher or equal index then `item`

Comment: Worked like a charm,but an extra note:  In case you are using a paginator or a sort for the material table, remember to update those. (e.g. `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;`)

Comment: ugly but it works

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the immutability is in game: the mat-table after it is intialized only listens to the datasource reference

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myDataArray">
```

So the datasource reference should be updated in some way after changing its content, for example

```js
  deleteTicket(rowid: number) {
    if (rowid > -1) {
      this.myDataArray.splice(rowid, 1);
      this.myDataArray = [...this.myDataArray]; // new ref!
    }
  }
```

or simplier

```js
  deleteTicket(rowid: number) {
    this.myDataArray = this.myDataArray.filter((item, index) => index !== rowid);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

After deleting the selected row, you have to reassign matDataTable again.

```
deleteTicket(rowid: number){
  // raw_data is the array of data that you getting from the db.
  this.raw_data.splice(rowid,0)
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me

```
removeData(i){
 this.count.splice(i,1);
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.myDataArray = this.myDataArray.filter((u) => u.id !== id);
```

OR

```
this.myDataArray.data = this.myDataArray.data.filter((u) => u.id !== id);  // <-- this works for my case
```

Courtesy: https://muhimasri.com/blogs/add-and-remove-table-rows-using-angular-material/

Answer (score 0):

First, find the index of a particular element
`let idx = this.SPARE_REQUESTED_DATA.findIndex((obj) => obj._id == id);`
after that remove that element on click
`this.dataSource.data.splice(idx, 1) // first argument idx of element and second argument how many items remove after that index`
after that refresh the data source
`this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription()`
once the updateChangeSubscription if you are using pagination and filter
`this.dataSource.sort = this.sort //Your sort method`
`this.dataSource.pagination = this.paginator //Your pagination method`
`this.cdr.detectChanges()` // changeDetectRef method from angular implement it in your constructur

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use `MatTableDataSource`.

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<T>(ELEMENT_DATA);

deleteFunction(item){
    // find item and remove ist
    dataSource.data.splice(this.dataSource.data.indexOf(item.id), 1);
}
```

Comment: pop only returns the last item in an element ?